# "An exception occurred during a WebClient request" when using the Task Scheduler

Tags: c#

I have a console app that downloads certain files from an FTP server. I'm using `WebClient` to do this like so:

```
var cred = new NetworkCredential(user, password);
var downloadRequest = new WebClient();
downloadRequest.Credentials = cred;
downloadRequest.DownloadFile(host + FileName, target + FileName);
```

This works perfectly when I run the app normally. However, I need to run this in the weekend so I have had Task Scheduler run it on Sunday. But when I do, I always get this error in my log:

`An exception occurred during a WebClient request`

When I rerun it manually, it works perfectly. Is there anything I'm overlooking?

Comment: Do you just log the exception message? It may have a full stack trace and/or inner exception that may help. There is nothing wrong with your code, anyway.

Comment: Is your app running as a different user from the scheduler?  If a local user, maybe the user isn't allowed access to that resource?

Comment: @Arran - Not right now, but I did change my code to log the whole thing. I'm just waiting for the right time to run it again and try to duplicate the problem.

Comment: @iMortalitySX - I don't think so. I didn't setup any different user when creating the task.

Answer (score 0):

This could help others looking for solution.

I believe this line:

`downloadRequest.DownloadFile(host + FileName, target + FileName);`

is doing the trick.  Somehow it just doesn't recognize the FileName (second parameter).

What worked for me is, I changed the above line to the following:

`downloadRequest.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(host + FileName), target + FileName);`